# How read between delimiters in php DOM of a XML file?

Tags: php, xml, dom, tags

I've some XML files and I've to read and convert them in HTML.

The format of the XML is this:

```
<book pages="2">

    <page n="1" />

    <entry>
        ...
    </entry>
    <entry>
        ...
    </entry>
    <entry>
        ...
    </entry>

    <page n="2" />

    <entry>
        ...
    </entry>
    <entry>
        ...
    </entry>
    <entry>
        ...
    </entry>

    <endpages />

</book>
```

How i can extract an array of the entries only of a single page?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you alter the structure? The page's should have the entries in them.

Comment: @chris85 They are 110 files then require too much time

Comment: Look into [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) if you already have a `DOMDocument` of your XML file. Then you can use an XPath query to select all `<entry>` tags under a `<page>` with a particular `n="x"` attribute.

Comment: Isn't there a end page tag?

Comment: @Andreas They are self closing.

Comment: @Andreas yes there is with another tag name but exists one updated with and example

Comment: @rickdenhaan This will be perfect but can you do an example? I don't have found a query that do this

Comment: You could split the `page` elements, then build the children as their own XML docs. @rickdenhaan xpath solution sounds cleaner though.

Comment: @chris85 I'don't understand what do you mean with split the page elements etc...

Comment: Something like this https://3v4l.org/iVmp3, that is pretty hacky though.

Comment: @chris85 interesting i will try with this method can be a good solution maybe thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggested using XPath for this in [my original comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47003245/how-read-between-delimiters-in-php-dom-of-a-xml-file/47005469#comment80953210_47003245), however, I've been playing around with some XPath expressions for this using a combination of `following-sibling` and `preceding-sibling` but I can't get it to work properly with this XML structure.

A bit of a hacky way of doing this is by just fetching everything after a given page number, and stopping when you find the next `<page />` or `<endpages />` element:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$dom->load($xmlFile);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$pageNo = 2;

$list = $xp->query("/book/page[@n='" . $pageNo . "']/following-sibling::*");

foreach ($list as $node) {
    if ($node->nodeName == 'page' || $node->nodeName == 'endpages') {
        break;
    }

    echo $node->textContent . "<br />"; // <entry /> node
}
```

I'm quite sure this will not perform very well if you have a lot of pages in the XML file and you're trying to fetch only the elements of page one, but in terms of lines of code this is overseeable and maybe someone else has some ideas on how to optimise the XPath expression.

Comment: At the moment this is the best solution I found thank you

Answer (score -1):

Easy in XSLT 2.0/3.0. First reorganize the XML into a more sensible structure:

```
<xsl:template match="book">
<book>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="* except endpages" group-starting-with="page">
    <page n="{@n}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group() except self::page"/>
    </page>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</book>
</xsl:template>
```

Then to process a selected page:

```
<xsl:param name="page-num"/>
<xsl:template match="page[@n = $page-num]">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

You can run XSLT 2.0/3.0 from PHP using the Saxon/C processor. No need to dive into low-level DOM manipulation.

Comment: I hate it when people downvote an answer without giving a reason. I can imagine some people might downvote this answer because they prefer writing 100 lines of DOM code to 20 lines of XSLT code. But not liking the answer doesn't make it wrong.

Comment: I don't have downvoted you and idk who downvoted you. Now i've upvoted you :). Anyway your method is the best that i've found and I seen this yet but unfortunately it require a server with Saxon and this is a problem for me because I don't have the privilege on this server. @Michael