# How read between delimiters "inside tag" in php DOM of a XML file?

Tags: php, xml, dom

I've some XML files and I've to read and convert them in HTML.

In refer to my last question: [How read between delimiters in php DOM of a XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47003245/how-read-between-delimiters-in-php-dom-of-a-xml-file/)

Now i've a new problem. Look at **chapters**.

The format of the XML is this:

```
<book pages="2">

    <chapter n="c1">

         <page n="1" />  <---


         <entry n="e1">
             ...
         </entry>
         <entry n="e2">
             ...
         </entry>
         <entry n="e3">
             ...
         </entry>


         <page n="2" />  <---


         <entry n="e4">
             ...
         </entry>

    </chapter>

    <chapter n="c2">

         <entry n="e5">
             ...
         </entry>
         <entry n="e6">
             ...
         </entry>

         <endpages />  <---

    </chapter>

</book>
```

@rickdenhaan explained me a solution that is that:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$dom->load($xmlFile);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$pageNo = 2;

$list = $xp->query("/book/page[@n='" . $pageNo . "']/following-sibling::*");

foreach ($list as $node) {
    if ($node->nodeName == 'page' || $node->nodeName == 'endpages') {
        break;
    }

    echo $node->textContent . "<br />"; // <entry /> node
}
```

But now the problem is that following-sibling::* catch only the entries of the same chapter of the "page" container then in this case i can't print entry[n=e5] and entry[n=e6]

How i can extract an array of the entries only of a single page?
How i can adapt this query?

Thanks in advance!

**-------- UPDATE --------**

Resolved with following::*

```
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$dom->load($xmlFile);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$pageNo = 2;

$list = $xp->query("/book/page[@n='" . $pageNo . "']/following::*");

foreach ($list as $node) {
    if ($node->nodeName == 'page' || $node->nodeName == 'endpages') {
        break;
    }

    echo $node->textContent . "<br />"; // <entry /> node
}
```

Comment: Resolved with  following::*

Comment: I removed "RESOLVED" from the title. If you have your own answer, post it below and rollback your post, or delete the question.